# Maldet - How to Exclude/Ignore a File From Scanning?

Tags: linux, malware

I am using maldetect on my server and a client is getting his file quarantined after maldet flags it as malicious.

```
{CAV}Atomicorp.Zip.File.Contains.exe  :  /home/timsffco/public_html/downloads/timsff.zip  =>  /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/timsff.zip.3026311886
```

We have determined that the file is NOT malicious.

Is there any way to tell maldet to ignore that file when scanning?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [official](https://www.rfxn.com/appdocs/README.maldetect) documantation

> .: 8 [ IGNORE OPTIONS ]
>
> There are four ignore files available and they break down as follows:
>
> /usr/local/maldetect/ignore_paths
> A line spaced file for paths that are to be execluded from search results
> Sample ignore entry:
> /home/user/public_html/cgi-bin
>
> /usr/local/maldetect/ignore_file_ext
> A line spaced file for file extensions to be excluded from search results
> Sample ignore entry:
> .js
> .css
>
> /usr/local/maldetect/ignore_sigs
> A line spaced file for signatures that should be removed from file >scanning
> Sample ignore entry:
> base64.inject.unclassed
>
> /usr/local/maldetect/ignore_inotify
> A line spaced file for regexp paths that are excluded from inotify >monitoring
> Sample ignore entry:
> ^/home/user$
> ^/var/tmp/#sql_.*.MYD$